# google map api is not able to find zipcode 22222

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geocode, google-geocoding-api

I saw zipcode 22222 is for Arlington, VA in United States but when search this from Google Map api it doesn't show me country name United States

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=22222

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in here?

I tried with http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|postal_code:22222&sensor=false
which gives no result that means United States doesn't have zipcode=22222
but on internet 22222 belongs to VA, US

Comment: How can it know what country you want to lookup with that zip code?
I think you need this format http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU|postal_code:2340&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks but still not working
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|postal_code:22222&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

Use zip_code not postal_code I think this returns the correct.

[http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|zip_code:22222](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US%7Czip_code:22222)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think zip_code is a valid parameter. Response will be same when you remove zip_code or write anything in place of zip_code. Secondly, with zip_code it should have given me the State name?

Comment: Well then I would just use (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US%7Cpostal_code:22206) and submit a bug report to google maps. Also this (https://goo.gl/dFJ8i2)